# Define absence of the alert Prometheus

Tags: yaml, prometheus, metrics, prometheus-alertmanager

I have alert for Prometheus set up in such a way that it depends on the absence of value for another alert:

```
  - alert: Some_Alert
    expr: |
      round(some_expr) > 24
      AND ALERTS{alertname="Empty_Source_Data_Load"} != 1
```

I want to calculate `Some_Alert` value only when the first expression is true and `Empty_Source_Data_Load` alert is absent (which means there is data). How can I do this using absent method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not use `absent` but rather the [unless](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) binary operator.

> vector1 unless vector2 results in a vector consisting of the elements
>   of vector1 for which there are no elements in vector2 with exactly
>   matching label sets. All matching elements in both vectors are dropped.

The alert would be something like the following (with an `ON()` clause):

```
  - alert: Some_Alert
    expr: |
      round(some_expr) > 24
      UNLESS ON() ALERTS{alertname="Empty_Source_Data_Load"}
```

Comment: Is the `(ON)` clause necessary in this expression? It looks like the expression might work without it.

Comment: It depends on the labels you have on each side. Without it, the label set must match the alert to take effect. I assumed it is not the case but you'll know better.